# ruby and ruby on rails book (2009)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What are the best Ruby / Rails book available right now ?

Note : I know that this question has probably been asked before.  But things change so much in the Ruby / Rails world that some of the books are not up to date or even teaches things that are deprecated in the newer release of Ruby / Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For learning Rails and Ruby, I typically recommend (and refer to!):

[Agile Web Development with Rails](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) - Pragmatic Bookshelf (and co-written by DHH - creator of Rails)

[The Rails Way](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321445619) - Addison-Wesley

[Programming Ruby (The pickaxe book)](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/ruby/programming-ruby) - Pragmatic Bookshelf

[The Ruby Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596516177) - O'Reailly

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best book is still [SitePoint-Patrick Lenz-Simply Rails 2](http://www.sitepoint.com/books/rails2/) and the unforgotten one [Agile Web Development with Rails, Third Edition](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition), but you can start with [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) to have a newbie tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

[Agile Web Development with rails](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition)
Head First Rails

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally see this book recommended, but if you are a PHP developer, [Rails for PHP Developers](http://railsforphp.com) is an excellent book.